# Custom text in mail template depending on shipping description

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, global-variable

I want to insert custom text in email template, if shipping title = 'Pickup'.
I have followed this guide to make if statement work in mail template.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797394/magento-email-template-if-statements

1. I have inserted this in mail template.

   ```
   {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/shippingmail.phtml' order=$order}}
   ```
2. I have created new phtml file called shippingmail.phtml
   with this code

   ```
   if ($this->getData('order')->getShippingDescription()=='Pickup') {
   echo nl2br(Mage::getStoreConfig('general/store_information/address')); }
   ```

But for some reason i can not make it show my store address i mail if shipping description is 'Pickup'.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Are you sure the correct file is included in the mail and did you check what the value of `$this->getData('order')->getShippingDescription()` is by echoing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out problem.

I had placed custom mail block "shippingmail.phtml" under my custom template.

Once i changed this this to default template it worked

Ie.

```
app/design/frontend/default/MYCUSTOMTHEME/template/email/shippingmail.phtml
```

Changed to this:

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/email/shippingmail.phtml
```

Comment: *scratches head* do email templates really not follow Magento's theme template sellection process? are you sure this was your issue?